# Basic question about lattices

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

I don't understand why $x \leq x \lor y$ and $y \leq x \lor y$ in the following basic lemma (taken from p.10, *Models and Ultraproducts*, Bell and Slomson (1969)):

> **Lemma 1.12**: If the Lattice $L$ contains a maximal element then this maximal element is unique.
>
> ---
>
> *PROOF*. Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are both maximal elements of $L$. Then $x \leq x \lor y$ and $y \leq x \lor y$ so that, since $x$ and $y$ are maximal, $x = x \lor y$ and $y = x \lor y$. Thus $x = y$ and the lemma follows.

From what elementary principle of lattices do $x \leq x \lor y$ and $y \leq x \lor y$ follow?

Comment: For every $x \in A$: $x \le \sup{A}$ for any subset $A$ of an ordered set. And $x \lor y = \sup\{x,y\}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not from an elementary principle of lattices, so much as from the definition of $\vee$.

In a lattice (or any poset), $a\vee b$ ($a$ join $b$) is defined as the least upper bound of the elements $a$ and $b$.  Of course, if $a\vee b$ is the least upper bound for the elements $a$ and $b$, it follows that it is an upper bound for them -- and therefore that $a\leq a\vee b$ and $b\leq a\vee b$.

The only thing that's special about a lattice here is that every two elements are guaranteed to have unique join and meet defined; you can actually take the definition of 'lattice' to be "a partially ordered set in which every pair of elements has a meet and a join".

Comment: Doesn't it also follow by definition of the order relation $\leq$ as $x \leq y$ iff $x \lor y = y$ (or is that only for Boolean algebras?)?

Comment: @user65526 That's right. From associativity and idempotency, it follows that $x \vee (x \vee y) = (x \vee x) \vee y = x \vee y$, yielding, by the equivalence that you mention, that $x \leq x \vee y$. (You can either prove it using the order relation, as Nick Peterson showed you, or using algebra and the axioms, this way.)